# How to power a Seeeduino Stalker v2.3 - water proof with charger instead of solar panel

Tags: power

I am currently coding on a Seeeduino Stalker v2.3 - water proof kit.

http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Seeeduino_Stalker_-_Waterproof_Solar_Kit

It is sold with a solar panel to recharge the battery. Unfortunately, I will not have a lot of light where my sensor will be installed and I would like to power the board with a charger from 110V-220V plug and keep the battery only for potential power shortage.

My questions are:

1. What is the best option for connection and charger?
2. I have a previous Arduino Uno charger (9V-1A). Would it work with some linear regulator? What wiring should I use?
3. Any recommendation for a Li-Ion battery that could I buy and that would last longer than this 3.7 V at 1000mA?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

1. To be as little invasive as possible, I'd remove just the [solar panel](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/05w-solar-panel-55x70-p-632.html?cPath=155) and replace it with a power supply with the same typical voltage (5.5V) and at least the same typical power output (0.5W). It should not be too difficult, nor too expensive. Any USB charger that can provide 5V should do. You can just cut the USB connector and attach the wires to the board. Or be more elegant and create an adapter. Either way should work. And the price should be about a couple of bucks.
2. Yes, I think it would work, although linear regulators 9V -> 5V are really inefficient. See my proposed solution from the previous point.
3. On ebay there's [plenty](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.Xlipo+3.7v.TRS0&_nkw=lipo+3.7v&_sacat=0) of options, but they might not fit in the box of the seeduino. You have to compare the dimensions of the battery vs whatever extra space might be available.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can charge the battery and power the board, via USB. The CN3063 requires between 4.4V to 6V, so not a huge range of options besides a 5v wall-wart
2. No. 9V would be too high.
3. How many mains power failures / brownouts do you get, where you live?

Comment: About point 2: @Somarinho proposed to use a linear regulator. While that would be highly inefficient, it could work.